# CONCAT() not returning requested string

Tags: mysql, sql

With this query, I want a name comprised of three fields to be returned. I don't understand why the `concat()` function is not returning all the requested values in the table. Some records will be filled--let `s say like 1-2-3. The result should then be "1 2 3". If the 3 records are 1-0-3 than the result should be "1 3." If the records are 1-2-0 then the result should be "1 2."

The three requested fields are all VARCHAR format.

[image: See my results here]
The first and second records are wrong, the third and fourth are right, then, again, some are right and some are wrong.

```
SELECT pt_rooms.room_id, pt_rooms.room_hotel_id ,
a_room_type.room_type_name, 
pt_rooms.room_title, a_room_type_suffix.room_type_suffix_name ,    
CONCAT(a_room_type.room_type_name,' ', pt_rooms.room_title,' ',   
a_room_type_suffix.room_type_suffix_name ) 
AS long_name FROM `pt_rooms` 
LEFT JOIN a_room_type_suffix ON   
a_room_type_suffix.room_type_suffix_id=pt_rooms.room_type_suffix_id 
JOIN a_room_type ON a_room_type.room_type_id=pt_rooms.room_type;
```

Comment: txs phroureo
     SELECT pt_rooms.room_id, pt_rooms.room_hotel_id , a_room_type.room_type_name, pt_rooms.room_title, a_room_type_suffix.room_type_suffix_name , 
  CONCAT_WS(' - ','a_room_type.room_type_name','pt_rooms.room_title','a_room_type_suffix.room_type_suffix_name') as long_name 
  FROM `pt_rooms` LEFT JOIN a_room_type_suffix ON a_room_type_suffix.room_type_suffix_id=pt_rooms.room_type_suffix_id JOIN a_room_type ON a_room_type.room_type_id=pt_rooms.room_type;

Comment: i have modifyed the query as per concat_ws documentation but stil i get wrong results

Comment: hi, ok it is solve now i had to remove backthicks in concat_ws() string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) will return `NULL` if *any* of the values passed to it are `NULL`.

To get around this, you can use [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', a_room_type.room_type_name, pt_rooms.room_title, a_room_type_suffix.room_type_suffix_name) AS long_name
```